# Induction proof that for all $n$ girls and $n$ boys there is never less girls than boys

Tags: discrete-mathematics, solution-verification, induction

Here's the question I'm trying to solve:

> Suppose that $n$ girls and $n$ boys are distributed around the outside of a circular table. Use mathematical
> induction to prove that for any integer $n \geq 1$, given any such seating plan, it is always possible to find
> a starting point so that if you travel around the table in a clockwise direction the number of girls you
> pass is never less than the number of boys you have passed.

The proof seemed a bit trivial so I'm a bit doubtful on whether I did it right. Any help is appreciated. As some context, $\mathbb{N}^+$ is used to represent natural numbers starting at 1. Here's my proof to it:

let $n_g$ be the number of girls and $n_b$ be the number of boys

Prove $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}^+, n_g \geq n_b$

let $S(n)$ be $n_g \geq n_b$

Base Case ($n=1$):
$$ 1 \geq 1$$
$$True$$

Inductive Hypothesis:

let $k \in \mathbb{N}^+$, assume $S(k)$ holds, ie, that $k_g \geq k_b$

Inductive Step:
$$S(k+1) = k_g + 1 \geq k_b +1$$
$$ = k_g \geq k_b $$

therefore, $S(n)$ holds for all $ n \epsilon \mathbb{N}^+$
QED

Comment: This is hard to follow.  Are you claiming that the desired property holds from *every* starting position?  But that's not true.

Comment: So you just begin using $n_g$ and $n_b$ without giving a definition for those?

Comment: MathJax tip: If you want set inclusion, use `\in` instead of `\epsilon`. Note the difference between `\forall n \in \Bbb{N}`, i.e. $\forall n \in \Bbb{N}$ and `\forall n \epsilon \Bbb{N}`, i.e. $\forall n \epsilon \Bbb{N}$ (not just in how epsilon looks, but also the spacing of the formula).

Comment: It seems like you've misunderstood the question. As you travel around the table, each time you pass someone, you should compare the number of girls and boys you've encountered so far. The problem asks you to prove that it is possible to find such a starting point that boys never outnumber girls in any of these comparisons.

Comment: hint, instead of boys and girls, imagine a bunch of stairsteps going up and down arbitrarily around the equator of some planet.  If you start walking from the lowest point, you can never get any lower, so the number of steps you go down can never be more than the number of steps you go up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have misunderstood the question.  You're not trying to prove the number of boys and girls are equal.  You're trying to prove that no matter how they're arranged, you can select a starting point so that the number of girls you've passed (in the clockwise direction) is at least as great as the number of boys you've passed *at every point in your journey*.

Base case:  $n=1$:  If you start with the girl, then the number of girls that you have passed will always be at least as great as the number of boys you have passed.

Inductive step:  Assume the hypothesis for $n=k$ and assume the circle has $k+1$ boys and $k+1$ girls.  Start with any girl and proceed clockwise until you reach a boy.  The first place where you reach a boy gives you a girl with a boy immediately next to her in the clockwise direction.  Temporarily remove that girl-boy pair from the circle, yielding a shortened circle with $k$ boys and $k$ girls.

Now apply the inductive hypothesis to the shortened circle to select a starting point.  By the inductive hypothesis, whenever you proceed clockwise around the shortened circle, you will always have passed at least as many girls as boys.  Reinserting the removed pair doesn't change that result, because you've selected the pair so that you pass the removed girl before you pass the removed boy.  Thus, the same starting point you picked for the shortened circle yields the result for the original circle.  This proves the inductive step.